# create large xml file

Tags: php, mysql

I work with Flex and PHP.

I do a query on mysql database and use php function to create xml.

The recordset may contain around 90000 rows. So generate the xml file is slow, around 50s.

I don't want to make a dump, but only create a file to send to Flashbuilder to create a dataprovider.

I tried to use several processes:

- DOMDocument
- XmlWriter
- SimpleXMLElement

But with those methods, time to create file is to slow.

Do you have another idea to accelerate process (mysql side or php side).

Thanks

Comment: By nature this is slow. You should be loading it in piece-by-piece as needed.

Comment: I'd also say that you must consider building your data provider in a way that does *not* involve dumping 90,000 rows in XML format to the client. Not only will the server be slow creating that, the client will have difficulties using it as well.

Comment: With 90000 rows you won't get any faster. Maybe if your database doesn't have indexes or they aren't setup correctly and you add them you will see some speed improvement, but as DanRedux said you should really load them piece by piece, or page by page, or depending how you need to handle/display them.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the structure of your XML? MySQL's command-line client can do XML output, this may help if your XML structure is very flat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution: create xml file with mysql command.
For example:

```
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, DB_PWD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link);

$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('\n<rec>\n', 
                CONCAT('\n<id>',acIndex,'</id>\n'),
                CONCAT('<prInitiales>',prInitiales,'</prInitiales>\n'),
                CONCAT('<acSolde>',acSolde,'</acSolde>\n'),

    '</rec>') SEPARATOR ' ' ) AS xml
    FROM Cutomer";

$recordset = mysql_query($query, $link);

$xml = mysql_fetch_array($recordset);
echo '<list>'.$xml['xml'].'</list>';
```

Thanks